# Article image doesnt show when sharing on twitter of facebook

Tags: facebook-share, twitter-share

I i am facing issue with issue with sharing articles on social media platforms. when i sharing an article it only show the title with link and no images shows up. Below is the meta tag description of sample article with dummy test and url

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="test sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sample" />
<meta property="og:description" content="test sample test sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sampletest sample &#8250;" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/programmes/some-article-here/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Test Site Name" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2023-05-25T07:16:29+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/sample-images-e1684998966221.webp" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="683" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="453" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/webp" />
```

Since we use article images as .webp format i hope that is not causing the issue. can some setting on plesk block image sharing when hosting linux on VPS